# Day Wise Searching in select query in mysql

Tags: mysql

i have a date field in my table in mysql . I want fetch record in a such a way that it gives record in the following manner from today to previous year.

id-->day-->counter

That means i want per day wise counter. In past year how many records were inserted in each day (sunday,monday,etc).

plz help
Thank You

Comment: This doesn't sound very hard.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DAY(dateField) AS dateDay, COUNT(*) AS numberOfDays
  FROM dateTable
    WHERE dateField BETWEEN TIMESTAMPADD(YEAR, -1, NOW()) AND NOW()
    GROUP BY dateDay
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_day

The DAY function can be replaced with DATE to get a full date, TO_DAYS to get a day number from the year 0, WEEKDAY to get Monday - Sunday, etc.

EDIT: To show by WEEKDAY, use DAYNAME function (DAYNAME(dateField))

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayname

Comment: Nice one Jeff....but if i want to show result as sunday monday wise then what will i do...

Answer (score 0):

Use previous `year` in where clause and count the occurrences grouped by `dayname` in each of `year`. And you can order the result on `weekday` numbers.

**Exampe**:

```
select   year( date ) as year
       , dayname( date ) as day
       , count( date ) as counter
  from table_name
 where 
       date between ( curdate() - interval 1 year ) and curdate()
       -- or the following, to match all from prev year
       -- year( date ) >= year( curdate() - interval 1 year )
 group by 1, 2 -- year and dayname
 order by year 
          , field( weekday( date ), 6, 0, 1, 2 ,3 ,4, 5 ) -- sun to sat
```